# When is it okay to use force unwrapping and/or disabling error propagation in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As someone who doesn't have too much experience coding apps I've always wondered a lot about this. Everywhere you look you will always find people saying that you should always avoid using `!` so as to make your code more safe. This is because crashes, even if they happen 0.001% of the time, are always a big **no** in programming. However, in some situations I can never really judge if it's okay to use the `!` operator. For example, let's say I have a function which updates a document in Cloud Firestore. Now there are two instances where you may possible use `!`. One is when you force unwrap the documents `id` property to reference the document and second is when you disable error propagation for `setData(from:completion:)`.

This is my reasoning for using `!` in both situations:

1. Force unwrapping the book's `id` property is fine because if I've fetched any books from Firestore, or created one using the initialiser, I will always fill in the `id` field with a value. The only way this may fail is if Firestore is unable to parse it into the field, which to my understanding only happens if you've annotated say a field called `name` with `@DocumentID` and the Firestore document has a field called `name` as well. This should never happen because I would never put a field named `id` in a book document.
2. `.setData(from:completion:)` should never throw either because it only throws if there's an error in encoding a `Book` instance. Again, this should never happen because firstly it's marked with `Codable` and also every book I add to the database will be by encoding that struct, guaranteeing it to work every time if it works once.

```
struct Book: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var title: String
}

func update(_ book: Book, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    let docRef = db.collection("books").document(book.id!)  //<<< Force unwrapping
    try! docRef.setData(from: book) { error in  //<<< Disabling error propagation
        completion(error)  // Any network related error thrown by Firestore is, however, handled
    }
}
```

Can someone please give me reasons as to why this should be avoided. If you think this has a chance to make the program crash make sure to explain the reason why it will crash as well so that I have a better understanding of these edge-cases.

If you have any personal experiences with anything even remotely related to this please share them as I would love to learn about them.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. This isn't restricted to *just* Firestore related situations, if you can share *any* situation in iOS programming where `!` can be used without problem (except for the obvious ones such as `URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!` or when using `.randomElement()!`) please do mention them.

Comment: If the property won't be `nil` in practice why do you use an optional at all? Non-optionals don't crash by definition.

Comment: @vadian To my understanding there's 1 situation in which the `id` property can be `nil`. If my book document looked like `{"id": "a1", "title": "a"}` then the `id` property would become `nil` since it's marked with `@DocumentID` but there's a field named "id" as well. In only this situation will it be `nil`, which like I said, shouldn't happen in my code. If the property won't be `nil` in practice then there's no need for using an optional, which is exactly why I'm asking if it's fine to always force-unwrap it. `@DocumentID` forces you to mark your property as an optional otherwise I wouldn't.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that `id` could be nil, therefore it's optional. Force unwrapping an optional is a bad idea as there's a reason it's optional in the first place. *I would never put a field named id in a book document* - is well intentioned but what happens if there's a typo, or some code is supposed to write to a *_id* field and it was coded as *id* instead. I've seen *dozens* of posts here where the poster is trying to track down a coding error but it was actually because the field being read is `user_name` but in the database it was stored as `user_naem`. Protect your code!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, that is a very fair question and can be confusing when you start dealing with optional types. When you are force-unwrapping a value, it means that you are sure that the value should be there. But `should` doesn't me it will be there.

In some cases, like you pointed out, there could be instances where, for reasons that you can't control like in your `Firestore` example, force-unwrapping a value could throw an error that you might not be prepared to handle.

After years of working on mobile apps, I learned that you have to use the common sense for such cases. There is no [silver-bullet](http://worrydream.com/refs/Brooks-NoSilverBullet.pdf) for such cases and it will depend on the risk you can afford to take when doing a force-unwrap.

Things you should consider before doing that:

- If you force-unwrap using the `!` operator and it throws an error, can you handle the error accordingly and perform other actions to mitigate the issue?

  - If yes, you can safely do it.
  - if not, you can consider using a [guard](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/understanding-swift/when-to-use-guard-let-rather-than-if-let) statement to protect you against failures and perform any actions where the expected value is `nil`.
- If you force-unwrap a value that your app or view controller needs to function in all cases and there is no way to recover from that, it's better to let it crash than to let the user perform actions in an invalid state. E.g. when a required ID is necessary to perform a transaction.

But like I mentioned before, it will depend on that affordances you can take when you do this kind of operation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I just wanted to know how am I supposed to realistically judge the risk involved in doing it. I get how some might say, "Well, just put `book.id ?? ""` if you're so worried" which fixes my issue in 1 line. But if I'm being realistic, will force unwrapping in this instance ever actually crash my app? If the answer is, "realistically, no" then I'd rather write `book.id!` and be more confident in my code. Similarly, in my encoding problem with `.setData(from:completion:)`, I don't think it'll ever crash, so in my head the risk is 0. But if I'm wrong please let me know.

Comment: Fair point @rayaantaneja. By definition, a force-unwrap means `this value is optional, so it might not be there`. In cases where you see APIs like this, most probably it's because they are written in Objective-C and are consumed in Swift. While the library authors or even Apple can guarantee that the value will never be null, the semantics of optionals are still there.
To your question about crashing the app, if you don't handle the error, it will crash your app. And like I mentioned in the answer, in certain cases crashing is better than an inconsistent state. But you are the judge of that.

Comment: Coming back to your initial question: `how am I supposed to realistically judge the risk involved in doing it.` This only you and your team can answer. that depends on how far you are willing to go with an app in an inconsistent state. Like I mentioned in my initial answer, one example is that if you can afford to perform transactions with an empty ID, that is fine. if you can't and there is no way to tell the user to try again, it's better crash the app. If you can show an error message to the user, then you can probably use a guard statement and handle that case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. The last thing I want to know since I'm not too experienced with Firestore is if the code in the original question will ever crash. If so under what condition would that happen?

Comment: Unfortunately I've never used Firestore, so I can't answer that, But if you look at the Firestore source code, we can see that it's written in Objective-C, which could probably explain the optionals there.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk

Comment: Alright, thank you so much you've been a great help. I guess I'll ask another question regarding if the snippet above would ever fail. Really appreciate it!