# Could using try! and force-unwrapping for updating data in Firestore cause a crash?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have this function which updates a `Book` document in Firestore. After looking over Firestore code a little bit I decided to disable error propagation (for `setData(from:completion:)`) and I'm also force-unwrapping an optional (`id` property of a `book` instance which is marked with `@DocumentID`). Obviously I shouldn't be doing this without being absolutely sure it won't crash however this is my reasoning for using `!` in both situations:

1. Force unwrapping the book's `id` property is fine because if I've fetched any books from Firestore, or created one using the initialiser, I will always fill in the `id` field with a value. The only way this may fail is if Firestore is unable to parse it into the field, which to my understanding only happens if you've annotated say a field called `name` with `@DocumentID` and the Firestore document has a field called `name` as well. This should never happen because I would never put a field named `id` in a book document.
2. `.setData(from:completion:)` should never throw either because it only throws if there's an error in encoding a `Book` instance. Again, this should never happen because firstly it's marked with `Codable` and also every book I add to the database will be by encoding that struct, guaranteeing it to work every time if it works once.

```
struct Book: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var title: String
}

func update(_ book: Book, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    let docRef = db.collection("books").document(book.id!)  //<<< Force unwrapping
    try! docRef.setData(from: book) { error in  //<<< Disabling error propagation
        completion(error)  // Any network related error thrown by Firestore is, however, handled
    }
}
```

Am I wrong in my assumption that this code will never cause a crash? If so, I am keen to understand the conditions under which an error might occur.

Comment: What is the difference to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392620/when-is-it-okay-to-use-force-unwrapping-and-or-disabling-error-propagation-in-sw)?

Comment: @vadian in the earlier question it was about using `try!` and force-unwrapping in general and this is for this particular case

Comment: The answer to your last question perfectly answers this question. The answer was not specific, and boils down to "Any time you force unwrap an optional it will crash if the value is nil". I am going to go upvote that answer now. Please re read it.

Comment: @Yrb I feel like I'm misrepresenting my question. I already know "Any time you force unwrap an optional it will crash if the value is nil". The question I'm asking is, "is my reasoning for this function **never** crashing correct?" I know if I "somehow" get a `nil` value my code will crash. What I'm saying is, however, that I'll **never** get a `nil` value given my reasoning. I just want someone to confirm or deny that. If I'm wrong and the code might actually crash, I want to know under what conditions/circumstances that might happen.

Comment: OIC. We can’t really answer your question with the information given. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The obvious answer is that your reasoning is flawed, and a nil is being passed. I would also try a simple `print("\(book.id ?? "book.id is nil")")` debug in the function to print out the id. When the app crashes, you will have a clear log, though the crash log is probably already telling you.

Comment: @Yrb I've never gotten a crash using this so far. All my `Book` instances always have the `id` property filled. And the book has never failed to be encoded. I don't understand how it's obvious that the code will crash can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @vadian I asked this question in a much better way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68411438/if-something-conforms-to-codable-can-it-ever-fail-to-be-encoded-or-decoded 

should I delete this question or let it be?

Comment: @Yrb I asked the question in a better way like you recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68411438/if-something-conforms-to-codable-can-it-ever-fail-to-be-encoded-or-decoded

Should I delete this post or let it be?

Comment: I misunderstood what you were asking. I assumed that the reason you were asking the question is that it WAS crashing, but you weren't sure where the problem was. I agree that the only way to be sure is to write appropriate units tests OR don't use an optional in this case. That is a design choice that you must make, and is a bit out of what SO is really for.

Answer (score 0):

(Answer by @JoakimDanielson and @Scriptable) If the instance conforms to `Codable` and you have enough controls to ensure the data will **always** be accurate, this code should never crash. You should write unit tests to help ensure this.

(Addition by @KirilS.) Technically, decoding may fail if your encoded data is missing a field such as the `name` field. The chance of this happening is low, but don't underestimate the possibility of "unexpected" change on the server. In addition, newer versions of your app may change the `name` property to an optional value, and someone using an older version of the app may get a crash if the value is `nil`. As mentioned, the chances are low, but never 0, so doing this isn't recommended as you can slip up very easily. And the slip up will be **very** detrimental to the user experience. So no point risking it.