# If something conforms to Codable can it EVER fail to be Encoded or Decoded?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I was wondering if an object which conforms to `Codable` can ever cause an error while in the process of being encoded or decoded. I feel as though conforming to the protocol *ensures* that an error can never be thrown.

For example if I have a `struct` called `Book`:

```
struct Book: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name: String
}
```

Can this `struct` **ever** fail to be encoded or decoded?
For example if I do:

```
try! docRef.setData(from: book) { error in _ }
```

I don't think this can **ever** throw an error *synchronously* if `Book` conforms to `Codable`.

Similarly,

```
try! docRef.data(as: Book.self)
```

should **never** throw because, again, `Book` conforms to `Codable`

If I'm wrong and `Book` may fail while being Encoded or Decoded please explain under what conditions/circumstances that might happen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you own and control both the custom type and the data source then it should never fail once it has been properly tested.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson What do you mean by properly tested? I do control both the "putting data into firestore" as well as the "retrieving data from firestore" aspects of it. It works perfectly fine when I encode and upload the data and then download and decode the data. Does this mean it's properly tested?

Comment: By properly tested I believe Joakin means that it should in theory work and never fail. as long as you have enough controls to ensure the data is accurate and in the right formats. unit tests will help to ensure this

Comment: @Scriptable Thank you so so much for your answers. I've literally been pulling my hair out about this for 2 days now. Super super grateful :D

Comment: Yes, with properly tested I meant tested after the development phase so that encoding/decoding works as expected.

Comment: Technically, since you have a required field `name`, it can fail/throw on decoding if that field is missing in encoded information. How likely that to happen depends on what you are decoding from. If it's information coming from server, never underestimate the possibility of "unexpected" change on the server. If it's your serialized data on disk for example, the likelyhood is low, but still: imagine the field `name` becomes optional on next version of your app. Someone upgrades to new version - no problem, but then they downgrade and get a crash...

Comment: @KirilS. Encoding an instance wouldn't **ever** cause any issues though, right?

Answer (score 2):

Encoding:

For JSONEncoder the cases where encoding fails are documented here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/2895034-encode.
Afaik assuming all properties and contained data structures are composed of simple types like Int, String, Array, Dictionary it will never fail because these values can be always represented as JSON. But you might have a type like Float that throws an Error when the value cannot be represented as JSON.

Decoding:

Any invalid JSON input like missing fields or syntax errors will throw an error. I recommend always handling these and making sure they don't go unnoticed / the user gets at least a "sorry, something went wrong, we're looking into it" experience.

Comment: Would you recommend using nil coalescing for things such as `book.id ?? ""` as well? Or is using force unwrapping for `@DocumentID` properties fine? i.e. `book.id!`

Answer (score 2):

As you asked this question in the context of Firestore, I'd like to add some more details in addition to what Ralf mentioned in his answer.

When decoding a Firestore document, there are a number of situations that might in a mapping error, which is why you should be prepared to handle them.

For example:

- Your struct might expect a field (i.e. it is non-optional), but the field is missing in the Firestore document. This might happen when you've got other apps (Android, web, or even a previous version of your iOS app) that write to the same document, but use a previous version of the schema
- One (or more) of the attributes on the document might have a different data type than your struct.

The following code snippet contains extensive error handling for these and other cases (please be aware that you need to adjust how to handle those errors to your individual situation - you might or might not want to display a user-visible error message, for example). The code is taken from my article [Mapping Firestore Data in Swift - The Comprehensive Guide](https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/#error-handling).

```swift
class MappingSimpleTypesViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var book: Book = .empty
  @Published var errorMessage: String?
  
  private var db = Firestore.firestore()
  
  func fetchAndMap() {
    fetchBook(documentId: "hitchhiker")
  }
  
  func fetchAndMapNonExisting() {
    fetchBook(documentId: "does-not-exist")
  }
  
  func fetchAndTryMappingInvalidData() {
    fetchBook(documentId: "invalid-data")
  }
  
  private func fetchBook(documentId: String) {
    let docRef = db.collection("books").document(documentId)
    docRef.getDocument { document, error in
      if let error = error as NSError? {
        self.errorMessage = "Error getting document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
      }
      else {
        let result = Result { try document?.data(as: Book.self) }
        switch result {
        case .success(let book):
          if let book = book {
            // A Book value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
            self.book = book
            self.errorMessage = nil
          }
          else {
            // A nil value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot,
            // or the DocumentSnapshot was nil.
            self.errorMessage = "Document doesn't exist."
          }
        case .failure(let error):
          // A Book value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
          switch error {
          case DecodingError.typeMismatch(let type, let context):
            self.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(context.debugDescription)"
          case DecodingError.valueNotFound(let type, let context):
            self.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(context.debugDescription)"
          case DecodingError.keyNotFound(let key, let context):
            self.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(context.debugDescription)"
          case DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let key):
            self.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(key)"
          default:
            self.errorMessage = "Error decoding document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you're curious about how Firestore implements the Codable protocol, head over to the [source code](https://cs.opensource.google/firebase-sdk/firebase-ios-sdk/+/master:Firestore/third_party/FirestoreEncoder/FirestoreDecoder.swift?q=DecodingError&ss=firebase-sdk%2Ffirebase-ios-sdk). For example, searching for `DecodableError` will show how exactly which error conditions might occur, and why.

Comment: Thanks.. My mapping was failing and I could not see why.  Misspelling in a property. Thanks!